# Check if SharePoint People Picker value is empty using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to display values of SharePoint Document Library(columns like Doc Type, Owner, Date, etc.) in a table view in a SharePoint page.

The columns "Doc Type" is a lookup value and Owner is People Picker value.This values can be empty as well. Hence, I need to check if this values are empty before I retrieve and display it.

For the Document Type the below code works but not for the people picker field:

```
if (currentItem.get_item('DocumentType') != null) {
    documentType = currentItem.get_item('DocumentType').get_lookupValue();
}
```

For People Picker I have used the below code:

```
if (currentItem.get_item('Author') != "") {
    authorizer  = currentItem.get_item('Author');
    authorizerName = authorizer.get_lookupValue();              
}
```

Comment: can you please share your code that you are using to validate people picker field ?

Comment: Hi Rohit, I have updated the code for your reference.

Comment: Hi, I am not sure but why don't you try to check for `!=null` instead of `!=""`.

Comment: No it doesn't work.